# CVE-ID: CVE-2022-29464 - Security Advisory WSO2-2021-1738

Tags: security, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We observed vulnerability `CVE-2022-29464` being exploited in the wild since April, allowing unrestricted file uploads resulting to arbitrary remote code execution (RCE) found from [here](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/22/e/patch-your-wso2-cve-2022-29464-exploited-to-install-linux-compatible-cobalt-strike-beacons-other-malware.html)

This affects WSO2 API Manager 2.2.0 and above, Identity Server 5.2.0 and above, Identity Server Analytics 5.4.0 to 5.6.0, Identity Server as Key Manager 5.3.0 and above, Open Banking AM 1.4.0 and above, and Enterprise Integrator 6.2.0 and above.

We're using WSO2 EI Product V6.4.0/6.5.0.

I have seen [Security Advisory WSO2-2021-1738](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/Security+Advisory+WSO2-2021-1738) guideline too.

We don't have Support Subscription, So I'm planning to remove `<FileUploadConfig>`mappings in the `<product_home>/conf/carbon.xml` as suggested in same WSO2 Security Advisory page.

Is this mitigations step enough or do we need to concentrate further more on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the advisory, it seems disabling the file upload services is not a complete fix. If you look at the fix that has been implemented it has code-level changes as well.[1]

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/pull/3152/files

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your information. As per your suggestion class level change also required, how can we replicate those changes in our WSO2 Product as we don't have a Support Subscription. may i know some other ways if possible?

Comment: This is a bit tricky. If you really want to get the code changes you can find the correct component version being used (You can check the plugins directory for this) in the product version you are using and manually merge the code changes and rebuild the source and then apply the new component as a patch. But I will not recommend this approach. What I can suggest is, make sure you minimize the risk by other means. For example, hardening network security, capping unnecessary OS permissions etc.